# How to make Task in JavaFX service constantly take arguments?

Tags: java, java-8, concurrency, task

I'm invoking a Task in JavaFX service doing something, and problem is the method in this service is taking arguments from UI elements only once...

code:

```java
    public void DoSomething(){ //this method is invoked when button is clicked
            ExampleService s = new ExampleService();
            s.setValue1(s1.getValue()); //s1,s2 - UI elements
            s.setValue2(s2.getValue());
            s.start();
        };

        private static class ExampleService extends Service<Void> {
            double value1,value2;
            public double getValue1() {
                return value1;
            }

            public void setValue1(double value1) {
                this.value1 = value1;
            }

            public double getValue2() {
                return value2;
            }

            public void setValue2(double value2) {
                this.value2 = value2;
            }

            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new Task() {
                    final double v1 = value1;
                    final double v2 = value2;
                    @Override
                    protected Object call() throws Exception {
                        while(!isCancelled())
                            ExampleMethod(v1,v2); // I want this method to take arguments from UI elements at each iteration
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        }
```

How to make method take arguments from UI elements at every iteration? I tried creating a Task in method `DoSomething()`, but that blocked the UI (and to be honest, that's weren't a good idea...)

Comment: [The documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) has examples.

Comment: what do you mean by "constantly take arguments" - take them from some queues one by one?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I mean take values from UI as arguments (e.g. from Sliders)

Comment: @VGR yeah, but I want to take values from UI and I can't find from documentation how to constantly take values from UI as arguments :/

Comment: Constantly, as in periodically?  Every *x* seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: @VGR more like after finishing methods iteration

Comment: Why can’t you just create a new Task after calling that method?

Comment: @VGR I'm not sure how to do that; I'm starting Service by clicking Button and that Service has task defined in `createTask()` method...

Comment: This is starting to feel like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Let’s step back and forget about Tasks entirely.  What are you trying to actually accomplish?

Comment: I want my method to take arguments from UI elements after every iterationI Have

Comment: @VGR I Have [this code](https://pastebin.com/GTA8kqMQ) which take arguments only once - after clicking button and I want my method to take arguments from UI elements after every iteration

Comment: Include that code in your question.  This discussion will be useless to future readers if we refer to a pastebin URL that no longer exists when others are reading this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206464/discussion-between-kris-1313-and-vgr).

Answer (score 0):

```
protected Task<Void> createTask(int i, int j) {
    return new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            while(!isCancelled()) {
                new InnerMethod(i, j);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```